# how to create/update models with many-to-many relationship in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two models/entities: `Company` and `Founder` with many-to-many relationship and Company as owning entity in back-end. Full stack app is developed with Jhipster 6.10.5. Angular is used for front-end. I want to create new company with its founders with reactive form.
The two Models are defined in angular as show down below - shown first `Company` followed by `Founder` model: the code used to create the new Company is also shown below.

I get two types errors.

> "Object is possibly 'undefined' for the following code shown in the code snippet below.
> founderFirstName: company.founders.founderFirstName,
>
> -Property 'founderFirstName' does not exist on type 'IFounder[]'
>
> ```
>  founderFirstName: company.founders.founderFirstName,
> ```

How could I define or access the elements in the Founder model/entity from company model?

The two models are show below:
1-Company.model.ts

```
import { ITeam } from 'app/shared/model/companyprofile/team.model';
import { IFounder } from 'app/shared/model/companyprofile/founder.model';

export interface ICompany {
  id?: number;
  companyName?: string;
  description?: any;
  teams?: ITeam[];
  founders?: IFounder[];
}


export class Company implements ICompany {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public companyName?: string,
    public description?: any,
    public teams?: ITeam[],
    public founders?: IFounder[]
  ) {}
}
```

2-Founder.model.ts

```
import { ICompany } from 'app/shared/model/companyprofile/company.model';

export interface IFounder {
  id?: number;
  founderFirstName?: string;
  founderLastName?: string;
  companies?: ICompany[];
}

export class Founder implements IFounder {
  constructor(public id?: number, public founderFirstName?: string, public founderLastName?: string, public companies?: ICompany[]) {}
}
```

Then in Company-update.component.ts, here is the class to create/update company with its founders where I am having the errors.

```
export class CompanyUpdateComponent implements OnInit {
  isSaving = false;
  founders: IFounder[] = [];
  teams: ITeam[] = [];

  editForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [],
    companyName: [null, [Validators.required]],
    description: [null, [Validators.required]],
    founders: this.fb.group({
         founderFirstName: [null, [Validators.required]],
         founderLastName: [null, [Validators.required]],
        }),

  });

  constructor(
    protected dataUtils: JhiDataUtils,
    protected eventManager: JhiEventManager,
    protected companyService: CompanyService,
    protected founderService: FounderService,
    protected teamService: TeamService,
    protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ company }) => {
      this.updateForm(company);

      this.founderService.query().subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IFounder[]>) => (this.founders = res.body || []));
      this.teamService.query().subscribe((res: HttpResponse<ITeam[]>) => (this.teams = res.body || []));
    });
  }

  updateForm(company: ICompany): void {
    this.editForm.patchValue({
      id: company.id,
      companyName: company.companyName,
      description: company.description,
      founders: {
       founderFirstName: company.founders.founderFirstName,
       founderLastName:  company.founders.founderLastName,
      },
    });
  }
 
  save(): void {
    this.isSaving = true;
    const company = this.createFromForm();
    if (company.id !== undefined) {
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.companyService.update(company));
    } else {
      this.subscribeToSaveResponse(this.companyService.create(company));
    }
  }

  private createFromForm(): ICompany {
    return {
      ...new Company(),
      id: this.editForm.get(['id'])!.value,
      companyName: this.editForm.get(['companyName'])!.value,
      description: this.editForm.get(['description'])!.value,
      ...new Founder(),
        founderFirstName: this.editForm.get(['founderFirstName'])!.value,
        founderLastName: this.editForm.get(['founderLastName'])!.value,
   };
  }
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me out on this.

Comment: As far as I can see there is confusion whether a company has 1 or more founders. Many places you expect only 1. You need square brackets for arrays, not curly braces. The last error is pretty selfexplanatory, it says what I just said. I think you need a FormArray for the founders. I also don't think you need the 2 model classes, only the interfaces, thats what I am used to anyway. But - I don't really understand the code

Comment: Thanks. FormArray is indeed the way to go about it.